# Python custom character/symbol/expression map to methods/functions

Tags: python, operators

Is it possible to map custom character/symbol to a class method like 
`+` is mapped to `__add__` and `+=` mapped to `__iadd__`

I have looked into `operator` module but there is no option to create a custom expression to map with a method.

Comment: Map a method with a char is easy, create a new symbol is impossible AFAIK. What are you trying to do exactly ?